# How can I search through the HTML source of an outside URL and return the results to my app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to search an outside url for content matching "title" and return the results to my HTML page in the background through Javascript. I have been using Javascript and not found any resources that resolve my query, maybe I'm asking wrong?

but I would basically search the document with :

```
var title = document.getElementsByName("title");
```

The hard part is connecting to the page and searching through the HTML source code.

TIA!

Comment: You can't generally get the content from an outside URL unless server specifically allows you to do so. But, you can do it from server side. You will be able to get the content of any URL from your server.

Comment: you can use jquery ajax to get page's HTML content. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ 

Parse HTML you got from ajax request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't generally get the content from an outside URL unless server specifically allows you to do so. But, you can do it from server side. You will be able to get the content of any URL from your server. Server must include an header in response with name [`access-control-allow-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) which contains patterns/name of your domain.

However, you can do it from server side anyway, unless you are blocked specifically by the server.

You will need to develop a solution in which you grab the content for your outside URL from your server. It can be anything like PHP, Node.js, C# etc. After receiving response from the external server, deliver it in response to the browser using `AJAX` or anything. Then you can play with it anyway you want using JavaScript or JQuery.

#### Important Note:

Make sure whatever you are trying to access in anyway, you are allowed to do so. If they (your outside URL) wants to share something with public, they must be providing some APIs or other solutions to allow you access to their content.

Comment: Thanks , that was  very thorough answer! Regarding your note, I was trying to achieve something through the provided API, however it required user authentication and that defeats the purposes of my application. And I only need to access one bit of publicly available information.

Answer (score -1):

Research has led to to a solution, implementing a **scraper**. There are many in existence,scrapy for instance. Just a head's up for those with the same question.